# Reference for global theory of Schrödinger operators

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde, schrodinger-operators

**Question.** What is a good reference to learn about the spectral properties of Schrödinger operators in $\mathbf{R}^n$? I am specifically interested in references that discuss examples where the potential is bounded, but does not have a sign. (See more details below.)

Let $L = \Delta + q$ be a Schrödinger operator defined on $\mathbf{R}^n$, where $\Delta$ is the standard Laplacian. The potential is regular and bounded:
$ -C \leq q \leq C $ for some constant $C > 0$. However, no sign is assumed for $q$, and in principle there is no sort of asymptotic decay.

I want to gain a better understanding of possible behaviour of the spectrum, eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $L$ on $\mathbf{R}^n$.  I am familiar with the classical elliptic theory on bounded domains—for example in that context the spectrum is discrete, $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$, the first eigenfunction is positive etc.

**Edit.** I want to emphasise that I am not asking for a reference that treats all operators $L = \Delta + q$ as above in one swoop. I would be happy with say, a textbook that imposes additional restrictions on the potential, especially if the methods were sufficiently flexible so as to be used more generally.

Comment: For such a general class of potentials, anything is possible, already in dimension $n=1$. In particular, there need not be any eigenvalues.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Hm, shoot, I had no idea. The operators I'm considering are linearised around solutions of another, semilinear PDE, so there is no explicit formula in terms of $x$. Do you have suggestions for natural additional hypotheses that would make the question more focussed, for example forbidding oscillations of $q$?

Comment: Yes, if $q\to 0$ at infinity and $q$ doesn't oscillate too much ($q\in BV$ would work as an assumption for $n=1$), then the spectrum looks "as expected": discrete spectrum below zero (possibly empty), purely ac spectrum on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: The standard reference for the whole subject is probably still Reed-Simon, vol. 3, 4, but there are also some newer books (none of which I have read).

Comment: @ChristianRemling Dang, imposing $q \to 0$ is something I wanted to avoid. In the example I had in mind the potential $q$ is (mostly) positive and bounded below, say something like $r^{-n} \lvert \{ q \leq C/2 \} \cap B_r \lvert \to 0$ as $r \to \infty$. In any case I'll take a look at Reed--Simon, thanks for the recommendation. I'm happy to look for other references myself; what are the key terms I should look for?

Comment: (1) For this kind of potential, you won't be able to say much in general. For example, a sparse perturbation of a constant potential can give purely sc spectrum (in $1$ dimension). (2) Some other authors of books on the subject are Hislop-Segal and Teschl.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks Christian, I appreciate your input.